# Perform recursive calculation based on previous days calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I have a table dbo.TrueMarginCalc which I need to perform calculate a weighted cost based on the date. I also have this spreadsheet which illustrates what I need to do. The table in the database is just like this.

In the image below this table is sorted by [Date] ASC and I calculate the first instance as so:

[image]

I need to then recursively calculate this again using the prior day's "Weighted True Cost" so on and so on:

[image]
[image]

My code is as such:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TrueMarginCalc 
(
    [WHS] varchar(3),
    [PRODUCT] varchar(5),
    [TRANS DATE] DATE,
    [RECEIPTS] INT,
    [TRUE COST] NUMERIC(18,8),
    [RUNNING_SALES] INT,
)

INSERT INTO dbo.TrueMarginCalc 
SELECT 
'350','54710','2018-09-06',42,0.7128,52   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-07',42,0.7154,61   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-08',42,0.715 ,42   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-10',0    ,0  ,37   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-11',42,0.7124,44   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-12',42,0.7125,42   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-13',42,0.7147,77   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-14',0    ,0  ,35   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-15',42,0.7123,47   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-17',0    ,0  ,22   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-18',42,0.7183,45   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-19',42,0.71  ,42   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-20',42,0.7124,56   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-21',0    ,0  ,10   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-22',42,0.7124,43   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-24',0    ,0  ,0    UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-25',42,0.71  ,41   UNION ALL SELECT
'350','54710','2018-09-26',42,0.71  ,54    

select *, (Running_Sales*[TRUE COST])/NULLIF(Running_Sales,0) As [Weighted True Cost] 
FROM dbo.TrueMarginCalc order by [TRANS DATE]
```

All this does is calculate that first day's Weighted True Cost. Does this require some sort of cursor or recursion to perform this in T-SQL?

```
;
WITH CTE AS (

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WHS, PRODUCT ORDER BY [TRANS DATE]) AS RNK, WHS,PRODUCT,[TRANS DATE], [RECEIPTS], [TRUE COST], RUNNING_SALES
, CAST((Running_Sales*[TRUE COST])/NULLIF(Running_Sales,0) AS MONEY) As [Weighted True Cost] FROM dbo.TrueMarginCalc 

UNION ALL

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WHS, PRODUCT ORDER BY [TRANS DATE]) AS RNK, WHS,PRODUCT,[TRANS DATE], [RECEIPTS], [TRUE COST], RUNNING_SALES
, CAST((Receipts*[TRUE COST])+([Weighted True Cost] * Running_Sales)/(Receipts+Running_Sales) AS MONEY) AS [Weighted True Cost] FROM CTE 
WHERE RNK = RNK - 1 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY [TRANS DATE] asc
```

The above code is theoretically what I need but I am most certainly using the terminator incorrectly as it spits out the exact same calculation as the anchor of the recursive CTE.

Comment: Please don't post images ofdata. Images of data are poorly received as the volunteers you're asking to help you can't make use of it. Please post your sample data, and expected results, as **formatted** `text` or as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements. Thanks.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Larnu I have added in the CREATE and INSERT. Thank you.

Comment: This question is well formatted and very clear, it is rare for a new user to make such quality post.

Comment: We can't see the formula from screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive cte for this, something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    -- numbering is required for rcte
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WHS, PRODUCT ORDER BY TRANS_DATE) AS rn
    FROM TrueMarginCalc
), rcte AS (
    -- base row for each partition
    SELECT *, CAST(TRUE_COST * RUNNING_SALES / TRUE_COST AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) AS WTC
    FROM cte AS base
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    -- next row for each partition
    SELECT curr.*, CAST(prev.WTC * curr.RUNNING_SALES / curr.TRUE_COST AS DECIMAL(18, 8))
    FROM cte AS curr
    INNER JOIN rcte AS prev ON curr.WHS = prev.WHS AND curr.rn = prev.rn + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM rcte
```

Unfortunately the formula is incomplete but the above query shows you how to access columns from current row and previous iteration.

Comment: Wonderful. I did have to edit the formulas (as you mentioned) but this does EXACTLY what I need. Genius!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% about the formula, but you can try this.

```
SELECT WHS, PRODUCT, [TRANS DATE], RECEIPTS, [TRUE COST], [RUNNING_SALES]
    , (
        CASE [TRUE COST]
            WHEN 0.0 THEN LAG([True Cost]) OVER(PARTITION BY WHS, PRODUCT ORDER BY [TRANS DATE])
            ELSE (COALESCE( LAG([True Cost]) OVER(PARTITION BY WHS, PRODUCT ORDER BY [TRANS DATE]), [TRUE COST] ) + [True Cost]) / 2
        END
    ) AS [WeightedTrueCost]
FROM dbo.TrueMarginCalc
```